# Ubuntu 18 hot key shortcut not working on ALT + Space

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, window, shortcuts

Recently I have upgraded to Ubuntu 18. One thing is not working which was really helpful as a developer, to avoid using mouse which is `ALT` + `Space`and then press `C` to close the window.

[image]

Please help.